# How to compute the volume of such a triangular prism shaped object

Tags: geometry, volume

like this :

[image]

where $z_i$ are not equal.

Comment: Are the segments labeled $z_i$ each perpendicular to the plane of the top triangle?

Comment: I cannot get link to see an image or $ z_i $ on it!

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes,just a normal triangular prism with three different height.

Comment: @Narasimham you can refer to the first picture in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism but with three different height.

Comment: Then the volume is simply $A(z_1+z_2+z_3)/3$ where $A$ is the area of the triangle (which can be found using the shoelace theorem). I'll let someone else prove this.

Comment: This can be considered a duplicate of [a later post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371139) which has more content.